# Multiple predecessors

Tags: ms-project

I have predecessor 46 and 147  on task 200.

Task 147 finish date is after task 46, but task 200 is starting the day after task 46, not after task 147 as expected.  How do I fix this?

I would expect MS projects to have a task start after the finish date of the predecessors with the latest finish date, not earliest finish date.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So there are 3 main ways this can happen:

1. Task 200 has an actual start date on it that is the day following the finish of Task 46 so it is ignoring the link from 147
2. Task 200 has a constraint that is forcing it to start at that time. This can happen with Start No Later Than, Must Start On, Must Finish On or Finish No later Than constraints. If it is anything OTHER than As Soon As Possible then change it to ASAP
3. The link between 147 and 200 is not a Finish to Start. Make sure it is a finish to start

Answer (score 0):

I can think about two possible causes:

- Check the relation between task 200 and task 147. The relation should
  be “FS” (finish to start) and should not have any lag value.
- Verify if task 200 has any date restriction. This is indicated by a
  calendar icon, in the information field (leftmost column in the
  Entry table, on a task view). Restrictions can force a task to start or finish at a certain date, regardless of its dependencies.

Hope this helps.

Greetings.